# Airflow:Passing of XCOM value to next task for each multiple tasks

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Requirement: Pass XCOM value from the previous task to the next tasks for each multiple tasks

**Error**: Error rendering template: can only concatenate str (not "set") to str

I tried as below

```
params={"s3_key": list(date.keys())[0]}
```

Reading the params in the SQL file code as below

```
 SELECT
    $1 AS json_array
FROM
    '@STAGE/' 
    (file_format = > 'public.s3_json',
         pattern = > '{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='api_into_s3_' + params.s3_key)[0]}}'
    )
```

Dag code

```
dats = [{f"date_{x}": (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")} for x in range(int(end_offset_days), int(start_offset_days))]

default_args = {
    "start_date": datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    "provide_context": True,
    "execution_timeout": timedelta(minutes=180),
}

with DAG(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=180),
    max_active_runs=1,
    params={},
) as dag:
    t0 = EmptyOperator(task_id="start_task")

    dates = dats
    api_tsk = []
    snflk_tsk = []
    for date in dates:
        api_tsk.append(
            APIOper(
                task_id=f"api_into_s3_{list(date.keys())[0]}",
                date_run=list(date.values())[0],
            )
        )
        snflk_tsk.append(
            SnowflakeOperator(
                task_id=f"s3_into_snflk_{list(date.keys())[0]}",
                snowflake_conn_id="snflk_conn_id",
                sql="queries.sql",
                warehouse="main_wh",
                schema="stg_sch",
                params={"s3_key": list(date.keys())[0]}
            )
        )

    t3 = EmptyOperator(task_id="end_task")

    t0 >> api_tasks

    for i, x in enumerate(zip(api_tasks, snflk_tasks)):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        else:
            api_tsk[i - 1] >> snflk_tsk[i - 1]
            api_tsk[i] >> snflk_tsk[i]

    snflk_tsk >> t3

    return dag
```

As below, the xcom value from api_into_s3_date_0 needs to be passed into s3_into_snflk_date_0 tasks and so on

[image]

***> UPDATES:*** below is the xcom value from the previous task

[image]

But in the log, the query is showing as

```
 SELECT $1 AS json_array
    FROM '@STAGE/' 
        (file_format => 'public.S3_JSON',
              pattern => a
        )
```

the SQL file has been updated as below
`pattern =>{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='api_into_s3_'+params.s3_key)[0]}}`

Comment: It seems like `xcom_pull` may be returning `None` and indexing a `NoneValue` raises. Is `APIOper` pushing a value in the XCOM store?

Comment: yes its pushing the value already .. i have updated the error

Comment: It appears that `params.s3_key` is coming up as a set. It this being overridden somewhere. I recommend to `str(params.s3_key)` and verify if the value is the one being passed in your `SnowflakeOperator` to initialize the task.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Error is `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str' is undefined`

`pattern => {{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='api_into_s3_'+str(params.s3_key))[0]}}`

Comment: Try writing `{% set s3_key = params.s3_key | string %}` at the top of your query to set a variable for the converted value, then `{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='api_into_s3_'+ s3_key)[0]}}`

Comment: Still i am seeing the query as value  `pattern => a` in the SQL log

Comment: That's because it's indexing the first letter in a string value. Use `ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='api_into_s3_'+params.s3_key)`

Comment: try to add [] in task_ids. task_ids=['api_into_s3_'+params.s3_key]

Comment: @OluwafemiSule It finally worked out  .. Is it possible to extract only numbers from the xcom in the SQL file .  Example xcom shows as `airflow/tss/20220620195650/`  I need to get value `20220620195650`, So that when I create table it will be like `table_20220620195650`

Comment: You can write a custom filter to extract the number from the path and configure that as a `user_defined_filters` in your DAG initialization. Another approach would be to push a `dict` to the `XCOM` store.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule How do push dict to XCOM

Comment: You could pass that as in the `params` since you have that information already before DAG initialization. `params=dict(zip(['s3_key', 'id'], list(date.items())[0]))`